# Can not fill form using python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to fill html form and get the intended result as i get when i fill manually. But I fail.

I am trying to fill the site `https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/login.php` with value `32000001`. So far my try is as below-

```
import requests

#LOGIN_URL  = 'https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/login.php'
#LOGIN_URL  = 'https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/authentication.php'
LOGIN_URL  = 'https://www.desco.org.bd/ebill/billinformation.php'

payload = {
    'username': '32000001',
    'login':'Login',
    'login':'true'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)#, verify=False)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print (p.text)
```

I have found that `login.php` redirects to `authentication.php` and it further redirects to `billinformation.php` which delivers the true data i needed.

Thanks in advance.

**N.B. I am not planning to use selenium since it is too slow for my case i.e. collect huge data from this site.**

Comment: you should open browser dev tools and check what actually posted(headers, body, etc).

Comment: @LeiYang I have tried thus.  So you see in the above code I posted where `LOGIN_URL` changed along with `payload`. But I failed.

Comment: The URL you have is not the API to which you can make a post request, in my opinion, although you may see it as it is in the Network tab of developer tools, but the actual API to which you can make a post request would be something else, masked out from general view, security being one o the prime reasons.

Comment: i don't believe the browser tell you there are two `login` values.

Comment: `@LeiYang`  Yeah! `login.php` redirects to `authentication.php` and it further redirects to `billinformation.php` automatically. When redircts to `authentication.php` browser posts `'login':'Login'`

Answer (score 0):

i am working for similar case, may be you would try using websockets:

```
import websockets
def process_function(message):
    # process the message

def server(ws:str, path:int):
    while True:
        message_received = await ws.recv() # receive from ui
        print(f'Msg [{message_received}]')
        message_to_send = process_function(message)
        await ws.send(message_to_send)  # send feedback to ui

server = websockets.serve(server, '127.0.0.1', 5678) # set the html to run in the same ip:port
```

Answer (score 0):

another try:

```
import json, requests

def do_auth(url):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept":'*/*'}
    body = json.dumps({'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'})
    r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=body, verify=False)
    print(r.status_code);     
    d = json.loads(r.text);     
    print(d['access_token']);     
    print(d['refresh_token'])
    return d['access_token'], d['refresh_token']

do_auth(url_auth) # authorization
requests.get(url_content, headers=headers, verify=False)  # get data
```

Comment: can one stackoverflow user have multiple answers in one question? i never knew.